# Windows 10 how to fix stuck on 'Applying PC Settings' during update

Tags: windows-10-preview

Trying to update windows 10 from build 9926 (the .iso from microsoft's website) too the newest build(10049 if I'm correct). The upload downloads and prepares seemingly okay, and The first two steps go just fine, but when I get to the third step, 'Applying PC settings', it hangs at 0%. I am able to force reboot the pc and windows reverts back to build 9926 just fine, and attemptimg to reinstall the update produces the same results. Any tips on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently all that was required is patience. It took a while to get going, but eventually showed some form of progress.

Comment: Sometimes Time is all you need - never watch ice melt because it won't..

Comment: Yeah right, on my system it took 2 hours to install.

Comment: this is a known bug with 10049. It installs a lot of MUIs during upgrade.